# How can i insert newline character('\n') when i use snprintf in C

Tags: c, formatting, printf, character, buffer

I tried this code

```
void print_formatted(void) {
    char buffer[100];
    char line[15];
    FILE* fp;
    char* message = "Hello World in C language"

    fp = fopen("test.txt","w");
    snprintf(line, 10, "%s\n", message);
    strcpy(buffer, line);
    buffer += 11;

    snprintf(line, 10, "%s\n", message + 10);
    strcpy(buffer, line);
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), 20, fp);
}
```

Expected Result(test.txt) :

```
Hello World in
C language
```

But Real result is(test.txt) :

```
Hello World in C language
```

Here is Buffer Memory :

```
.
.
[10] = '\0'
[11] = 'C'
[12] = ' '
[13] = 'l'
.
.
```

How can i insert '\n' data instead of '\0'.
And How can i print formatted..

Comment: The null-terminator character is `'\0'`. The character `'\n'` is a *newline*.

Comment: As for what happens, I suggest you step through the code statement by statement in a debugger to see what happens.

Comment: Oh, the code in invalid by the way, it won't compile. `buffer` is an array which means `buffer += 11;` is not valid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude buffer is pointer. SO it can work

Comment: `char buffer[100];`? No it's not a pointer. And your code doesn't print anything so we can't tell about the expected or real results. Please create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok

Comment: As for the question of "[h]ow can I insert '\n' data instead of '\0'", the answer could simply be `buffer[10] = '\n';`. Or `buffer[strlen(buffer)] = '\n';`

Comment: `buffer += 11;` did your compiler like that line?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Hmm.. It is appending way. I need formatted way.

Comment: @4386427  The problem is shorter string inserted '\n' character. But a longer is not.

Comment: @TEom : The code you showed doesn't imply the need for formatting. You appear to just want to split a string, and write the two halves to a buffer with a newline in between, then write that buffer to file. So, eg., append the first half to the buffer, then append a newline, then append the second half. If you want to achieve something else, you'll have to explain exactly what you want, and make sure the code matches that.

Comment: @TEom There is something very wrong here! **The posted code can't compile!** However, you do say that you have a "real result". That can't be... You need to post the real code - this can't be it! BTW: Read http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3p.html (the section about snprintf) it has all the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code can't be your real code. The posted code can't compile.

Here:

```
char* message = "Hello World in C language"
                                           ^
                                           Missing ;
```

Here:

```
buffer += 11;

error: assignment to expression with array type
```

Anyway - your problem seem to be a misunderstanding of `snprintf`

From http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3p.html we have

> The snprintf() function shall be equivalent to sprintf(), with the
>          addition of the n argument which states the size of the buffer
>          referred to by s.  If n is zero, nothing shall be written and s may
>          be a null pointer. Otherwise, **output bytes beyond the n‐1st shall be
>          discarded instead of being written to the array**, and a null byte is
>          written at the end of the bytes actually written into the array.

So what does this mean?

Well assume you have:

```
char line[15000];
snprintf(line, 10000, "%s\n", message);
```

In this case there are plenty of room in the destination buffer so `line` will be

```
"Hello World in C language\n"
```

That is all characters from `message` plus the `'\n'` from the formatting string.

When you change the code to:

```
char line[15];
snprintf(line, 10, "%s\n", message);
```

You'll only get the first 9 characters of the above string - so you get the following value in `line`:

```
"Hello Wor"
```

So the `'\n'` has been cut off together with parts of `message`.

There are many ways to add that `'\n'` - here is one:

```
char line[15];
int n = snprintf(line, 10, "%s\n", message);
if (n > 9)
{
    line[8] = '\n';
}
else if (n > 0)
{
    line[n-1] = '\n';
}
```

In your case this will result in `line` being:

```
"Hello Wo\n"
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer.